# Python: Using subprocess to give input to another program

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to use Python to automate running another program repeatedly.  Right now I am typing the following into the command line, one at a time (the numbers come from the file "Avals"):

```
advisersProgram
input1
0.01
input1
0.015
exit
```

When I try to automate it, I can launch advisersProgram but I can't send it the inputs.

This is what I have tried:

```
import os
import glob
import subprocess

files = sorted(glob.glob("*"))
for f in files:
    os.chdir(f)
    As = [float(line.strip()) for line in open("Avals")]
    subprocess.call('advisersProgram')
    for A in As:
        subprocess.call('input1')
        subprocess.call(A)
    subprocess.call('exit')
    os.chdir("..")
```

I have also tried

```
for f in files:
    As = [float(line.strip()) for line in open("Avals")]
    subprocess.call(['advisersProgram','input1',A[0],'input1,A[1]','exit'])
```

and

```
for f in files:
    As = [float(line.strip()) for line in open("Avals")]
    subprocess.Popen('advisersProgram',stdin=['input1','0.01','input1','0.015','exit'])
```

Other info:
I looked into Pexpect (I am not sure if this would be useful but it was suggested in one of the stack exchange answers I read), but I do not have that installed and do not have the authority to install it.

I don't need to capture any output; advisersProgram generates contour plots which are saved in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Consider passing a list of command line parameters in the *args* argument of [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), not in the *stdin* argument. Below shows how stdin (standard input) can be used to output to Python console the output and/or error of child process.

```
import glob, os, subprocess

# PATH OF PY SCRIPT (CHANGE IF CHILD PROCESS IS NOT IN SAME DIRECTORY)
curdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))   

files = sorted(glob.glob("*"))
for f in files:                 # NOTE: f IS NEVER USED BELOW, SHOULD IT BE IN OPEN()?
    As = [float(line.strip()) for line in open("Avals")]
    for A in As:
        p = subprocess.Popen(['advisersProgram', 'input1', A], cwd=curdir,
                   stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        output,error = p.communicate()  

        if p.returncode == 0:            
           print('OUTPUT:\n {0}'.format(output.decode("utf-8")))            
        else:                
           print('ERROR:\n {0}'.format(error.decode("utf-8")))
```

Of course if you do not need any output, remove such lines but you may want to track which child processes worked or not.

Comment: # NOTE: f IS NEVER USED BELOW, SHOULD IT BE IN OPEN()?
Sorry; I was using f to change directories; I have edited the original question.

Comment: That's a question to you. Is "Avals" one of the many glob files? If you only open one file, no need to loop. If one of many files, then include loop with `open(f)`.

Comment: When I enter 'advisersProgram' in the command line, or use `subprocess.call('advisersProgram')`, I get the following:

`PV-WAVE v10.1  UNIX/Windows/VMS
% Compiled module: X.
WAVE> `

Using your suggestion with `print('OUTPUT:\n {0}'.format(output.decode("utf-8")))`, I get a bunch of:

`PV-WAVE v10.1  UNIX/Windows/VMS`

It appears on the terminal once for each A value.  That is, it doesn't make it far enough to ask me for input.

Comment: What input should it ask? What is the executable program for "advisorsProgram"? Usually, one puts both the exe and file name then arguments. For instance calling an R script (which I have done numerous times from Python): `RScript.exe SomeCodedProgram.r arg1 arg2`.

Comment: It is a PVWave program.  I type "wave" to launch it (with no extension).  It doesn't take arguments, it takes user input after it starts.

Comment: Whatever you type in the command prompt, power shell, or terminal window is exactly what you include in `subprocess.Popen()`. Now please note,  the PVWave may have its own command line client (which is an executable, distinct from command prompts on your OS). This solution runs program in background where input is sent as arguments not waiting for user input.

Answer (score -2):

Ah, I was wrong - it wasn't `communicate()`. You just want to setup `stdin` as a [`subprocess.PIPE`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin)

```
import sys
import subprocess


def call_myself():
    print('Calling myself...')
    p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, __file__], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    for command in ['input1', '0.01', 'input1', '0.015', 'exit']:
        p.stdin.write((command+'\n').encode())


def other_program():
    command = None
    while command != 'exit':
        command = input()
        print(command)
    print('Done')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        if sys.argv[1] == 'caller':
            call_myself()
    except IndexError:
        other_program()
```